# Putting React app into production with Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, webpack, yarnpkg

React newbie here. I'm just about finished my first React app but running into issues with putting it into production

Currently, I'm attempting to run

```
NODE_ENV=production webpack -p
```

with a script in my **package.json** file.

Everything runs without issue but the script doesn't seem to be outputting the correct production **index.html** file. For instance, all of the JS and CSS files have a question mark and random characters appended to the end of them like this

```
href="/css/app.css?287deee1465dba65696e"
```

Also the production index.html file only seems to have what's written in the **/src/index.html** which is in my dev environment but I want it to be what's in **/src/App.js** where the meat of my code is written.

I must have something off somewhere but since I'm fairly new to both Webpack and React, I'm not sure where to begin to look. Below is my index.js, index.html, and a segment of my webpack.config.js that involves putting the code in production. 
**index.js**

```
//const css = require('./app.scss');
const css = require('./style/style.scss');

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import anime from 'animejs';
import {App} from './App.js';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')

);
```

**index.html(src)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
  </head>
  <body >
     <div id="root">
          <h1>Webpack</h1>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV ===  'production'; //true or false

var cssDev = ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'];

var cssProd =   ExtractTextPlugin.extract({

fallback: 'style-loader',

            use: ['css-loader','sass-loader'],
            publicPath: '/dist'
        })
var cssConfig = isProd ? cssProd : cssDev;

module.exports =  {

entry:{
    app: './src/index.js',
    slideshow: './src/js/slideshow.js',
    shapallax: './src/js/shapallax.js',
    yona: './src/js/yona.js',
},
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    // path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
},
```

I'm sure there are details I'm missing out that would be useful for solving this so please let me know the correct things to be looking for and asking.

Comment: Does the app load in development?

Comment: Yes. It first loads the index.html(dev) and a split second later the code from App.js is loaded.

Comment: Webpack configuration is sometimes a pain in the ass. My guess is that you have something that's changing the output file name: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-filename Is the webpack config file you posted everything in that file?

Comment: No, that's just an excerpt with what I think deals with the production output the most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out the issue which was fairly simple. In my **webpack.config.js** I had to change the **filename** in my **ExtractTextPlugin** setup. After removing a forward slash I had at the beginning of the path, I was able to get everything to output correct in my **/dist** folder. The final working setup is shown below.

```
 new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: 'css/[name].css',
        disable: !isProd,
        allChunks:true
    }),
```